# Search for files names within given convention

Tags: vb.net

Below find example of file which are downloaded to some directory. I got this given file name convention. "SSUP-RX-" is statis no changable.Rest could be changed as username, date and time.

```
SSUP-RX-admin-2014_12_2-9_16_5_69.csv
```

What i need to do i have to search for that cain of files in given directory and then extract the date and time from it. What is the best way to search for such cain of files and how to read date/time from it after?

P.S Probably after user name is year, month, day, hour,minutes,seconds, milisends

Comment: You could use a regular expression a.k.a regex to match the pattern.

Comment: [Whats have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) Please [post your code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm not pretty sure if I got your question correct, I think you are trying to get the name from the file and extract it or clean it up so that for example file name is: 
test-2015-01-28-14-15-30-9.csv

So for that the simple way will be retrieve the file name as is and use regex as it has been said to only extract what you want and you can use it as you wish.

Here is how to use regex:

visualbasic.about.com/od/usingvbnet/a/RegExNET.htm

Check out this under check USA Telephone number it similar to what you want:

visualbasic.about.com/od/usingvbnet/a/RegExNET_2.htm

Hope this answer your question.